# Как получить буфер вывода записанный при вызове dbms_output.put_line?

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

Есть функция:

```
function func_list(
    par1 varchar2, par2 varchar2, par2 varchar2, 
    p_lst out sys.odciVarchar2List) return varchar2;
```

Вызываю её так:

```
DECLARE
  lst  sys.odciVarchar2List;
  st varchar2(20);
BEGIN
  st:= func_list('PAR1','PAR2','PAR3', lst);
  for i in 1..lst.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(lst(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

Как в Python получить буфер вывода, который записывается при вызове `dbms_output.put_line`?

Пробовал `callproc`, но ничего не выводит. Возможно проблема в `out odciVarchar2List`.

Comment: Вроде можно вызывать `dbms_output.get_line` из Python. Посмотрите пример: https://gist.github.com/TerryMooreII/3773572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В отличае от IDE, где часто вывод разрешён по умолчанию, в Python скрипте надо явно включить вывод *до выполнения блока*, который производит вывод. Подробнее [в оф. док.](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html#using-dbms-output).

Воспроизводимый пример (установите `chunksize` для большего кол-ва выводимых строк):

```
sql = """
    declare
        lst sys.odciVarchar2List := sys.odciVarchar2List ('PAR1','PAR2','PAR3');
    begin
        for i in 1..lst.count loop
            dbms_output.put_line ('lst('||i||')='||lst(i));
        end loop;
    end;
    """  
cursor.callproc ("dbms_output.enable")
cursor.execute (sql)

chunksize = 100
lines = cursor.arrayvar (str, chunksize)
numlines = cursor.var (int)
numlines.setvalue (0, chunksize)

while True:
    cursor.callproc ("dbms_output.get_lines", (lines, numlines))
    nl = numlines.getvalue()
    linearr = lines.getvalue()[:nl]
    for line in linearr:
        print (line or "")
    if nl < chunksize:
        break
```

Выведет:

```
lst(1)=PAR1
lst(2)=PAR2
lst(3)=PAR3
```